# Swift - compile program with input parameters

Tags: swift, input, compilation, command, arguments

I have the following program in Swift (`myscript.swift`):

```
print("Enter x: ");
var x = readLine()!
print("x is " + x)

print("Enter y: ");
var y = readLine()!
print("y is " + y)
```

And I have an input file that contains the following (`input.txt`):

```
4
6
```

Usually, I compile using `swift myscript.swift`. However, I want to compile by passing the input file so that I am not prompted for input at the terminal. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @MartinR I managed to get the solution by myself. I am posting it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The command to compile is  as follows:

```
swift myscript.swift < input.txt
```

There is no need for additional swift code.